# MxGraph - Javascript function for ID value for the cell

Tags: mxgraph, jgraph

When we drop and drag the object into diagram canvas, the id attribute is assigned to that object. The id values are unique one. Which Javascript function in mxgraph called for the assign id value for the cell?

Comment: It is related to Mxgraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mxGraphModel.prototype.createId
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help